# Textbox disappears x64/x86 Touch Devices XAML Monogame

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, textbox, monogame

I got a weird problem with our game. When you get a highscore we enable a Xaml Textbox so you can tap it and call the onscreenkeyboard. but lately this kinda broke. I create a textbox inside my .xaml and turn it on visibility.collapsed and called it txtTest. When I'm loading my game I connect an eventhandler onto it

```
txtTest.PointerPressed += txtTest_PointerPressed;
txtTest.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerEventHandler(txtTest_PointerPressed), true);
```

When I enter the highscore screen an event fires that turns the textbox visible but on 0 opacity and sets the location and size.

```
Thickness margin = txtTest.Margin;
margin.Left = 1350 * _game.scale.X;
margin.Top = 770 * _game.scale.Y;
margin.Bottom = 240 * _game.scale.Y;
margin.Right = 200 * _game.scale.X;
txtTest.Margin = margin;
txtTest.Width = 300 * _game.scale.X;
txtTest.Height = 70 * _game.scale.Y;

txtTest.MaxLength = 10;
txtTest.Text = string.Empty;
txtTest.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
txtTest.Opacity = 0;
```

When we first ran this everything went great but lately it stopped working. The problem is that the textbox gets created and all the values are getting set but it just doesn't show. The textbox got a location and Visibility.Visible so it should just draw but it doesn't.

This currently only happens on native Touch Enabled devices as the Surface Pro or the Acer W500. When running this on a RT device or running on a desktop it works just fine and we are able to click on it with our mouse but when running Touch Enabled devices not even the Handlers fire it just feels like the textbox isn't even there. Even if I set the Focus on it nothing happens.

Anybody got any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 has the strange behavior of forcing your DPI Scale onto your Metro apps which especially influence your XAML elements. If you run your game on a 10,1" screen on 1920x1080 will result into a DPI Scale of 140 so your effective resolution will be

1920 / 1,4 = 1371
1080 / 1,4 = 771

Since in the question I put the margin.top on 770 you will draw the textbox in the last pixels and thereby not see it being drawn because of the effective resolution of 1371x771

So the proper way to do it will be checking what the Scale factor is and divide your margin by that value.

```
var scaler = 1f;

if (Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale == Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Scale180Percent)
{
     scaler = 1.8f;
}
else if (Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale == Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Scale140Percent)
{
     scaler = 1.4f;
}
else if (Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale == Windows.Graphics.Display.ResolutionScale.Scale100Percent)
{
     scaler = 1.0f;
}

Thickness margin = txtTest.Margin;
margin.Left = (1350 * _game.scale.X) / scaler;
margin.Top = (765 * _game.scale.Y) / scaler;
margin.Bottom = (220 * _game.scale.Y) / scaler;
margin.Right = (250 * _game.scale.X) / scaler;
txtTest.Margin = margin;
```

This will fix it and init the textbox on the right way.